# How do I keep a process going multiple times until a user decides otherwise? Java

Tags: java

So, I have made a program that calculates change when given a price (plus 5% tax) and a user given payment. The remaining requirements I need for this code is to:

1. Have the program loop until the user decides to exit the program
   by entering a `0` or any negative number (i.e `-2`).
2. If the user does not enter enough of a payment to cover the price, keep asking user to "Please enter payment amount" until the user has entered a large enough payment.
3. Print and display the correct amount of change and how much of each currency piece. The max price, without tax, is $500.00.

A full output, with all possible user choices should look like:

```
Cost of transaction (enter 0 or negative to exit; max is $500.00): 1000
Cost of transaction (enter 0 or negative to exit; max is $500.00): 501
Cost of transaction (enter 0 or negative to exit; max is $500.00): 500
Amount due (with 5.00% tax): $525.00
Please enter payment amount: 1000.57
Change back $475.57
$100: 4  $50: 1  $20: 1  $10: 0  $5: 1  $1: 0  $0.25: 2  $0.10: 0  $0.05: 1
$0.01: 2
Cost of transaction (enter 0 or negative to exit; max is $500.00): 0
Done.
```

This is my code below:

```
/*
* @author (Zach Daly)
* <p> (MakeChange.java)
* <p> (Project2)
* <p> (Make change)
*/

import java.util.*;

public class MakeChange
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double price;
        double amountPaid;
        int paidInt;
        int priceWithTaxInt;
        double priceWithTaxDbl;
        final double TAX_RATE = .05;
        int change;
        int hundreds, fifties, twenties, tens, fives, ones, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies;

        System.out.print("Cost of transaction (enter 0 or negative to exit; max is $500.00): ");
        price = in.nextDouble();
        priceWithTaxDbl = price + (price * TAX_RATE);
        System.out.printf("Amount due (with 5.00%% tax): $%3.2f\n", priceWithTaxDbl);
        System.out.println("Please enter payment amount: ");
        amountPaid = in.nextDouble();
        paidInt = (int) (amountPaid * 100);
        priceWithTaxInt = (int) (priceWithTaxDbl * 100);

        if (price <= 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Done.");
        }

        change = paidInt - priceWithTaxInt;
        double changePrint = (double) change / 100;

        System.out.println(changePrint);

        if (change == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Exact change! Amazing!");
        }

        if (paidInt > priceWithTaxInt)
        {
            hundreds = change / 10000;
            if (hundreds > 0)
            {
                change %= 10000;
            }

            fifties = change / 5000;
            if (fifties > 0)
            {
                change %= 5000;
            }

            twenties = change / 2000;
            if (twenties > 0)
            {
                change %= 2000;
            }

            tens = change / 1000;
            if (tens > 0)
            {
                change %= 1000;
            }

            fives = change / 500;
            if (fives > 0)
            {
                change %= 500;
            }

            ones = change / 100;
            if (ones > 0)
            {
                change %= 100;
            }

            quarters = change / 25;
            if (quarters > 0)
            {
                change %= 25;
            }

            dimes = change / 10;
            if (dimes > 0)
            {
                change %= 10;
            }

            nickels = change / 5;
            if (nickels > 0)
            {
                change %= 5;
            }

            pennies = change;

            System.out.printf(
                    "Change back $%.2f\n$100: %d   $50: %d   $20: %d   $10: %d   $5: %d   $1: %d   $0.25: %d   $0.10: %d   $0.05: %d   $0.01: %d\n",
                    changePrint, hundreds, fifties, twenties, tens, fives, ones, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies);
        }

        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: While this meets some requirements of the [mcve] requirement, it fails on others. It's runnable - fine, but not minimal. Asking the user for a number, do some dummy transformation - let's say just print it out, then asking for the next number or a termination response, would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is a do-while loop. It will run once, and keep repeating until the while condition is not met:

```
do {
        System.out.print("Cost of transaction (enter 0 or negative to exit; max is $500.00): ");
        price = in.nextDouble();
        //repeating logic

        if (price > 500) {
            price = 0;
            System.out.println("Maximum price was exceeded");
        }
    } while (price >= 0);
```

Comment: I will try that! Thank you!!

Comment: Now my only problem is adding the restriction of the max user entered price being $500.00 without tax. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the easiest and quickest solution would be to use a negative like -1 as your sentinel to exit. Then add a conditional within the do loop to check if the price exceeds 500 and if so, reset price to 0. I updated the snippet to reflect